# Plugin steps disabled after managed solution import

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a customer site when we import the next version of our managed solution, most of the plugin steps get disabled on the environment.
This does not happen on any other customer's site or even on the same org  is restored anywhere else.

We are using CRM 2013 on-premise.

I have tried to search online about what could be causing this, but no luck.

Any ideas what could be causing the plugin steps to be disabled?

Comment: Are the steps registered in the sandbox? Do the server trace files give you a clue?

Comment: If assembly isn't sandboxed the user deploying the solution needs to be a deployment administrator.

Comment: The assembly isn't in sandbox mode and yes, the solution is deployed by a deployment administrator